# Who is Cyclonus?

Tags: transformers

I think every Transformers fan knows this question, but it *really* bugs me. I have been driven nuts by it, so I'm asking, who is Cyclonus?

We know that in *Transformers: The Movie*, when Unicron reformatted several Decepticons into his servants, Thundercracker became Scourge, and Kickback and Shrapnel both became Sweeps.

But when Unicron reformats Skywarp and Bombshell, they both appear to become Cyclonus. After this scene, there is only one Cyclonus throughout the rest of the movie, as well as in season 3 of the TV series. Even though Unicron says "Cyclonus, the warrior... and his armada" when Skywarp and Bombshell are reformatted, we don't see much of this "armada", and you have to wonder if it were really there at all.

I have always been on the Skywarp team, but sometimes you do have to question your loyalties. *Who* is the one and only Cyclonus?

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly based on opinion matter on who you see is Cyclonus from the G1. Not even 'ask Vector Prime' was it answered, and it was asked twice.

First time it was asked:

> Q: Was Cyclonus built from Bombshell or Skywarp?
>
> A: It varies by universe.

Second time it was asked:

> Q: Dear Vector Prime,
>
> In the G1 universe, who was Cyclonus created from - Bombshell or Skywarp?
>
> A: Dear Inquisitive Fan,
>
> I feel as if I have answered this before. Perhaps you should read this to see which topics I have already covered.
>
> Though it is currently lacking the answers I gave to the writers of The Complete AllSpark Almanac, I am certain the industrious editors of the Transformers Wiki will rectify that oversight in the near future.

As a fan standpoint, it makes more sense for Skywarp to be Cyclonus. However, in development, it would be Bombshell that becomes Cyclonus.

They even tried to clear it up by featuring Cyclonus and Skywarp together in a comic.

Source from Tfwiki:

> in 2001 the Universe: Featuring the Wreckers comic stars Cyclonus and Skywarp side-by-side in the future... The 2007 conclusion of that storyline contains an exchange between the two wherein Cyclonus says that Skywarp had once been his "Armada". Skywarp retorts that he had always disliked Cyclonus, even when Cyclonus had been "a bug".

There has been a few more times they had tried to clear it up, by doing the same thing, that Bombshell is Cyclonus and Skywarp is the armada.

In the behind the scenes, looking at the storyboard, it was just Bombshell that was in the shot that was to be recreated into Cyclonus.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[The script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/transformers.html) doesn't specify which Transformers become Scourge and Cyclonus:

> ON CYCLONUS  (NEW DECEPTICON WITH PLANE TRANSFORM ABILITY)
>
> CYCLONUS is CREATED and then his "armada" of similar, but smaller and
>   similarly colored and clad creatures are formed.
>
> ```
>           UNICRON
>
>   Cyclonus, the warrior...and his armada.....
> ```

The visual shot of this scene has Bombshell clear in the foreground, with what appears to be Skywarp in the background:

[image: Before transformation]

And they are transformed to look like this:

[image: After transformation]

They then transform and the Bombshell-Cyclonus flies into the centre of the shot as the voice of Unicron says "Cyclonus.. the warrior"...

[image: Cyclonus]

Also note that Skywarp-Cyclonus appears slightly smaller than Bombshell-Cyclonus (although hard to tell because of the perspective) and is a slightly different colour, as mentioned in the script.

Based on this sequence of events I think it's fairly certain that *Bombshell* is Cyclonus, and Skywarp becomes one of the "armada".

Comment: It may not have said it in the script, but it does say it on the storyboard. https://tfwiki.net/mediawiki/images2/b/b6/Bombshell-to-cyclonus-storyboard.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I always believed it to be Skywarp.  The Insecticons never seamed to be loyal lieutenants like skywarp and thundercracker.  Throughout season 3, scourge and cyclones played similar roles as the jets - star scream, skywarp and thunder cracker.... so that makes the most sense.

Comment: Agreed. Skywarp becomes Cyclonus, Thundercracker becomes Scourge and the Insecticons become the Sweeps. Matches colours and is most logical.

Comment: Have you got any sources to support the idea that Skywarp is Cyclonus?